# Can I use Soundcloud api with a external url?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, soundcloud, internet-radio

I want to use a external radio url. But when I try to configure out my config class I didnt get a good result.

For example:

**Original config working:**

```
public interface SCService {

    @GET("/tracks?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID)
    public void getRecentTracks(@Query("created_at[from]") String date, Callback<List<Track>> cb);

}
```

**I tried it:**

```
@GET("myURL?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID)
    public void getRecentTracks(@Query("created_at[from]") String date, Callback<List<Track>> cb);
```

I didnt use SOundCLoud api I dont know If i can do it with this API. I am looking forward to have a app Android to playing streaming audio url.

Comment: COuld abit more context (lines of code) help us help you find the answer? I for one, do not understand but that you removed the enclosing "public interface SCService {}" block. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using retrofit. There has to be a Config class. Something like this:

```
public class Config {
public static final String CLIENT_ID = " Your id";
public static final String API_URL =  "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/channelname/";
}
```

so you must have a client id from the sound cloud API. You can get one by registering in their service for free.

Then, in your service interface you could use it like this:

```
public interface SCService {

@GET("/tracks?client_id=" + Config.CLIENT_ID)
public void getRecentTracks(@Query("created_at[from]") String date, Callback<List<Track>> cb);
```

Comment: I meant I had it beofre, but I changed. Because I want to play a track in my soundcloud account!  I would like to use souncloud like my webservices to consume this audio. Did I explain  me?